# Why can't I see a many-to-many relationship option?

Tags: sql-server-2017

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/bi-directional-cross-filters-tabular-models-analysis-services?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017), starting with SQL Server 2016+, bidirectional filtering was introduced to eliminate DAX queries need for many-to-many relationships to be created.

I set the filter directions to both tables on my tabular project:

[image]

As you can see, a many-to-many relationship still doesn't show up.

We have a requirement for many to many but why can't I see it even though I have SQL Server 2017 and VS 2017?

Comment: you want many to many just don't use a filter -- filters are when you want to limit what it can do.

Comment: @Hogan but a filter must be selected...theres no filter none option...

Comment: don't select "to both tables"?

Comment: @Hogan then the default option is <<To table1 something like that, which means its a one table filtering, which doesnt show the many to many option either.

Comment: what options does it show... I'm guessing one of them has many... which is what you want if you are just filtering one table.

Comment: @Hogan the filter direction shows only 2 options: option1: << To table1 and option2: << To Both Tables >> .  neither option shows a many-to-many cardinality option, its only the 3 that you see in the image

Comment: I am unable to explain this better.